# QGIS no longer remembers Python window position

Tags: qgis

My QGIS no longer remembers the last position of the Python Console after I've closed QGIS.

Every time I start QGIS and open the console it will dock below the map. I drag it to the top and save the project. When I open QGIS and Python console it appear below the map again.

I've also tried creating a new profile but that did not solve the problem.

I have version 3.32.0 (I dont know which version I had previously), maybe something have changed in this? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe since this one : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/1822998bda8b43054e1eab33c47f8202925c4fef, not really sure ...